# Javascript init class properties before calling super

Tags: javascript, class, subclass

i'm trying to convert my javascript classes from old style to new style. The problem is, that with the new style JavaScript requires that in a constructor `super` is called before accessing `this`. I have to extend a class that i am not the owner of and in that constructor it calls a method that i overwrite where i use my own properties. How to solve that?

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.create()
    }

    create() {}

    reload() {
        this.create()
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(options) {
        super()
        this.options = options
    }

    create() {
        let title = this.options.title // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a guard in B's `create`, and have its constructor execute it again:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.create();
    }

    create() {
        console.log("I don't want to run this");
    }

    reload() {
        this.create();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(options) {
        super();
        this.options = options;
        this.create(); // ... but now
    }

    create() {
        if (!this.hasOwnProperty("options")) return; // not now...
        let title = this.options.title;
        console.log("title", title);
    }
}

let b = new B({ title: "my title" });
console.log("let's reload");
b.reload();
```

Comment: Thank you, I‘ve ended up using this approach as it seems the most readable to me.

Answer (score 2):

```js
class A {
  constructor(opts, arg) {
    this.opts(opts);
    console.log('prop in the parent constructor', this.p)
  }
  opts(opts){}
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(opts, arg) {
    super(opts, arg);
    console.log('prop in the child constructor', this.p)
  }
  opts(opts){
    console.log('before even constructor of class A called, this is called. Can be used to assign options')
    Object.assign(this, opts)
    
  }
}

let b = new B({
  p: "my prop"
}, "some normal arg");


// you can also use it without any opts

console.log('---')
let c = new B({}, "some other arg");
```

this is what I like to do for the options that are needed in the parent class

Comment: This is a clever idea! I like it! I will try it out the next time i come across this issue. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I'd make the prototype's `create` a no-op, and then call a function after the `super()` is done.

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.create()
    }
    create() {}
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(options) {
        super()
        this.options = options
        this.createB();
    }

    createB() {
        const title = this.options.title;
        console.log(title);
    }
    create() {}
}

new B({ title: 'foo' });
```

I suppose you could also assign to `.create` after the super runs, turning it from a no-op back to your desired functionality.

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.create()
    }
    create() {}
}

function createB() {
}
class B extends A {
    constructor(options) {
        super()
        this.options = options
        this.create = () => {
            const title = this.options.title;
            console.log(title);
        };
        this.create();
    }
    create() {}
}

new B({ title: 'foo' });
```

Comment: thank you. doesn't look good, but it's a workaround. The problem is, that the `create` method is also called from within other methods where i would need my implementation. overriding those methods and copying all of the implementation from the parent class just to call my `createB` method would render the whole point of extending classes pointless :(

Comment: This is one of the reasons I avoid classical inheritance in JavaScript when I can - it just isn't flexible enough for some situations. It feels like shoehorning a paradigm from Java or some OO language into JS, which just doesn't work well sometimes. Using plain functions most places works better, at least for me. I suppose you could assign to `.create` after the super runs, turning it from a no-op back to your desired functionality.

Comment: Yeah seems like a really strange implementation. But your tip of reassigning works perfectly.

`this._create = this.#_create;
this._create();`

can you update your answer so I can accept it?